# How to call Actions.[SCENE_Name] in another function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a question.
How do I call the `Actions.Home()` function in the `login` function.
`Actions.home()` is apart of `react-native-router-flux` Actions and should change to another scene and that works fine but I can't call it inside the login function

I have looked around and haven't found anything about it.
Is it impossible or have I just missed something obvious.

```
async login(email, pass) {

email = this.state.email,
pass = this.state.password

if(email != '' && pass != '')
{
  try {
      await this.props.firebase.auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
          //this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'Chat' });
          Actions.home();

      console.log("Logged In!");


  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString())
  }

}
else if (true) {
  this.popup.alert('The Input fields havent been properly filled in');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported it at the top?

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
```

Comment: Yes Actions.home() works just not in the login function

Comment: No there is no error message it just reaches the Actions.home() method and then stops..